# Testing admin custom action with form

Tags: python, django, testing

I am developing a small django project to help administrate my dance school(my hobby)
So the app has some courses and for each course has many classes or lessons.
in the django admin in the course_changelist url i added a custom action create lesson with a custom form CreateLessonsDatesForm with 2 charfield a start_date and a end_date.
This actions basically create a lesson of that course. So for example if the course is on weekly basis every Wednesday, the action will automatically create a lesson of that course every Wednesday from the start date until the end date

The action works fine on browser but when tested it doesn't create any lesson.

I create a second action "prova" just to double check, it simply change the vowels of the place field in all i, without passing any form value, and it works. So probably i am missing something when using the form with the tests.

Thanks a lot

here's the code:

```
#core/models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, \
    PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _


class Course(models.Model):
    """
    Blueprint course it contain information about what style is taught,
    the time and place and the frequency
    """
    stile = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[('L', 'Lindy Hop'),
                                                ('J', 'Solo Jazz'),
                                                ('B', 'Balboa')],
                                                 default='L')
    level = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    time = models.TimeField()
    day_of_the_week = models.IntegerField(choices=[
                                            (1, 'Lunedì'),
                                            (2, 'Martedì'),
                                            (3, 'Mercoledi'),
                                            (4, 'Giovedì'),
                                            (5, 'Venerdì'),
                                            (6, 'Sabato'),
                                            (7, 'Domenica')
                                            ],
                                             default=3)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    frequency = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[
                                                ('W', 'Settimanale'),
                                                ('M', 'Mensile'),
                                                ('S', 'Occasionale'),],
                                                 default='W')

    def __str__(self):
    return "{} {}, {} il {} {}".format(
        self.get_stile_display(), self.level, self.place,
             self.get_day_of_the_week_display(), self.time)


class Lesson(models.Model):
    """
    The specific lesson held on specific day
    """
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    day = models.DateField()
    note = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[
                                                ('C', 'Chiuso'),                                                  ('M', 'Monthly'),
                                                ('A', 'Annullata'),
                                                ('H', 'Festa'),
                                                ('O', 'Open'),
                                                ('R', 'Regolare'),
                                                ],
                                                 default='R')


    def __str__(self):
    return "{}, del {}".format(
        str(self.course), self.day)



#backoffice/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from core.models import Student, Payment, StudentCourse, ClassRegister, Course, \
                    Lesson
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from .actions.back_actions import create_lessons, prova
from .forms import CreateLessonsDatesForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [create_lessons, prova]
    action_form = CreateLessonsDatesForm

    def update_status(self, request, queryset):

    if 'apply' in request.POST:
        queryset.update(status='NEW_STATUS')
        self.message_user(request,
        "changed status on {} orders".format(queryset.count()))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())
    # return
    update_status.short_description = "Update status"


from django.contrib import admin
from core.helpers.lessons import create_periodic_event
import datetime



#backoffice/actions/back_actions.py
from django.contrib import admin
from core.helpers.lessons import create_periodic_event
import datetime

@admin.action(description='Crea Lezioni')
def create_lessons(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    start_date = request.POST['start_date']
    end_date = request.POST['end_date']
    day, month, year = start_date.split("-")
    start_date = datetime.date(day=int(day),
                           month=int(month), year=int(year))
    day, month, year = end_date.split("-")
    end_date = datetime.date(day=int(day), month=int(month), year=int(year))
    for item in queryset:
    create_periodic_event(item.id, start_date=start_date,
                          end_date=end_date)
    # return {'start_date': request.POST['start_date'],
    #         'end_date': request.POST['end_date']}

@admin.action(description='Prova')
def prova(ModelAdmin, request, queryset):
    for item in queryset:
    item.place = change_vowels(item.place, 'i')
    item.save()


def change_vowels(text, v):
    return "".join([is_vowel(l) for l in text])

def is_vowel(l):
    if l in 'aeou':
    return 'i'
    if l in 'AEOU':
    return 'I'
    return l


#core/helpers/lessons.py
from core.models import Course, Lesson, StudentCourse, ClassRegister, Payment
import datetime


def create_periodic_event(course_id, start_date, end_date):
    """
    Function create lessons from starting date to end_date, example
    if course has weekly frequency on wendsay, function create a class every
    wendsay until reaches end_date, for the moment works only with week frequency
    """
    if isinstance(start_date, datetime.date) ==False:
    year, month, day = start_date.split("-")
    start_date = datetime.date(int(year), int(month), int(day))
    year, month, day = end_date.split("-")
    end_date = datetime.date(int(year), int(month), int(day))
    #read course
    c = Course.objects.get(id=course_id)
    next = start_date + datetime.timedelta(
                    c.day_of_the_week - start_date.isoweekday()
                    )
    if next < start_date:
    next = next + datetime.timedelta(7)
    ls = []
    while next <= end_date:
    Lesson.objects.create(course=c, day=next)
    ls.append(next)
    next = next + datetime.timedelta(7)


    return ls


#backoffice/forms.py

from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin.helpers import ActionForm

class CreateLessonsDatesForm(ActionForm):

    start_date = forms.CharField(max_length=10, required=False)
    end_date = forms.CharField(max_length=10, required=False)


#backoffice/tests/test_actions.py

from django.test import TestCase
from core.models import Course, Lesson
from django.urls import reverse
from django.test import Client
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib import admin
import datetime

class BackOfficeActionTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

    self.client = Client()
    self.admin_user = get_user_model().objects.create_superuser(
        email='admin@something.com',
        password='password123'
    )
    self.client.force_login(self.admin_user)
    self.course1 = Course.objects.create(
        stile='L', place='Body Experience',
        day_of_the_week=3, time='20:30', level='1',
    )

    def test_action_create_lesson(self):

    url = reverse('admin:core_course_changelist')
    start_date = datetime.date(2021,9,27)
    end_date = datetime.date(2021,11,27)

    start_date = "27-09-2021"
    end_date = "27-11-2021"
    res = self.client.post(url, {'action': 'create_lesson',
        'start_date': start_date,
        'end_date': end_date,
        '_selected_action': [self.course1.pk],
        # admin.helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME: [self.course1.pk]
        }, follow=True)
    # print ("response: {}".format(res.status()))
    print ("course PK: {}".format(self.course1.pk))
    self.assertEqual(Lesson.objects.all().count(), 9)

    def test_action_prova(self):
    """
    test a prova action, it changes it vowels of the title in all i
    """
    url = reverse('admin:core_course_changelist')
    res = self.client.post(url, {'action': 'prova',
        '_selected_action': [self.course1.pk],
        # admin.helpers.ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME: [self.course1.pk]
        }, follow=True)
    self.assertEqual(Course.objects.get(id=self.course1.pk).place,
                    "Bidy Ixpiriinci")
```

Comment: please check the code indents to understand blocks of code.

Comment: Thanks, need to rewrite probably, when i copied and paste as code it did mess up thing... Tried to fix but clearly didn't end well...